# Funciones php en ajax

Tags: php, ajax, funciones

Buenas, estoy con un pequeño drama en mi front end.. Pues estoy queriendo mostrar con while, todos los registros de una tabla, lo que sucede es que dos campos son ID de otra tabla, pero cuando inserto dentro de la concatenación la función para hacer el cambio de texto por ID, no me refleja nada, en PHP puro si lo hace, pero cuando está llamando por AJAX, no aparece nada.. Acompaño el código. Alguien podrá darme una mano?

Aquí se muestran todos los registros recuperados de la BD.

```
            <div id="resultado-registro">
                <?php include('destacados.php'); ?>
            </div>
```

Y aquí donde se preparan (solo coloco la parte final, si es necesario más info, me avisan).

```
$output = '';
if(!empty($faq)) {
$output .= '<input type="hidden" class="pagenum" value="' . $page . '" /><input type="hidden" class="total-page" value="' . $pages . '" />';
foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
    $output .= '

    <div data-id="'.$faq[$k]["id"].'" class="item item'.$faq[$k]["id"].' image-present align-center item-featured reviews-enabled">
                        <a href="imagenes/servicios/'.$faq[$k]["imagen"].'" target="_blank" rel="item-gallery" class="cboxElement">
                        <div class="item-thumbnail">
                            <div class="item-thumbnail-wrap">
                                <img src="imagenes/servicios/'.$faq[$k]["imagen"].'" alt="" class="imagen" alt="'.$faq[$k]["nombre"].'">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-text">
                                <div class="item-excerpt">
                                    <p>
                                        '.$faq[$k]["resena"].'
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-title">
                            <h3>'.$faq[$k]["nombre"].'</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-categories">
                            <span class="item-category">'.$faq[$k]["rubro_id"].'</span>
                            <span class="item-category">'.$faq[$k]["localidad_id"].'</span>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="review-stars-container">
                            <div class="content">
                                <a href="servicio.php?id='.$faq[$k]["id"].'">VER</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        ';
}
}
print $output;
```

Como podran ver, donde dice RUBRO_ID y LOCALIDAD_ID es donde quiero aplicar la funcion para que de la otra tabla, recupere el nombre de cada rubro y localidad según su ID.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias buscar y devolver nombre del **rubro** y la **localidad** en la misma consulta que haces al traer los productos.

**1.-** Suponiendo que la relación producto/rubro y producto/localidad es **1:1**, puedes, por ejemplo, hacer uso de la funcion **JOIN**:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT P.*,
  R.nombre AS nombreRubro,
  L.nombre AS nombreLocalidad
FROM productos AS P
INNER JOIN rubros AS R
  ON R.id = P.rubro_id
INNER JOIN localidades AS L
  ON L.id = P.localidad_id';
```

**2.-** Si la relación fuera **1:N** (un producto tiene mas de un rubro o localidad), podrías buscar todos los rubros y localidades previamente, guardarlos en una matriz donde el indice sea el Id y luego hacer referencia al mismo:

```
<?php
// Vale la pena destacar que si son muchos los rubros y localidades
// esto puede ser poco eficiente
<span class="item-category">'.$rubros[$faq[$k]["rubro_id"]].'</span>
<span class="item-category">'.$localidades[$faq[$k]["localidad_id"]].'</span>
```